# I want show different forms with different form IDs

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query31)){
    echo "<p class='fill'>".$row1["reg"]." asked:-" ;
    echo '<br>&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row1["question"].'"<br></p>';

echo '<form id="forms" method="post" style="display:none;" >';
echo '<textarea rows="2" cols="80" name="ans" class="form-control"> 
</textarea>';

echo '<button class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-medium w3-medium w3- 
margin-top w3-right" type="submit" name="answer">submit</button></form>';
echo '<button class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-large w3-margin- 
top show_button2" id="show_button2">Answer</button>';
}

<--Javascript code-->
$("#show_button2").click(function(e) {
$("#forms").show();
$("#show_button2").hide();
e.preventDefault();});
```

I'm trying create a "answer" button beneath each question which when clicked will display a textarea for typing answer. But I can't do it because of same form ids or button ids each time created in that LOOP. Can anyone please tell me how to give different ids or how to solve this problem. I will be highly obliged.

Comment: Create a counter, increase it and add to form id. Or use unique id if you have it in a `$row`.

Comment: but how will i access the id in javascript

Comment: You can add data-attribute to button, with same value as form id. Or use some DOM traversing like `closest('form')` or something similar.

Comment: _Tip:_ If you want your code to be more readable, you can close your PHP-block `?>` before outputting your HTML. When you're done, you can open the PHP block again: `<?php`. That would make IDE's to highlight both the PHP and HTML properly and it will make it easier to find potential typos etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply  but can you please write the code of what you suggesting or modify mine. That will be really helpful.

Comment: You can also select the buttons based in their class instead of their id, which is more common when you output stuff in lists.

Comment: As **Magnus Eriksson** has suggested, use a `class` [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9wm8wx54/)

Comment: Yeahhh!! It worked!! Thanks a lot @NewToJS and Magnus Eriksson. you solved a big problem for me.